# Why is there no vote option on low quality post reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, voting, low-quality-posts

Today I was reviewing some *low quality posts* and came across [an answer that was simply wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26462625/1847340). I checked the reason why one would flag a question as low quality and it says:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

On the other hand the [privileges FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) clearly state:

> #### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and **perhaps dangerously incorrect**.

I ended up commenting and downvoting it, as well as recommend deletion although I feel like the answer should not necessarily be deleted.

In my opinion voting down would've been a more appropriate solution but there was no option to downvote an answer directly from the *review tool*.

Comment: You are determining if the post should be deleted or not. Downvoting has nothing to do with if the post should be erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something that doesn't really make sense to me...but maybe it's just me being weird ;(

You were reviewing a **question** that was flagged with low quality flag.

Your task was to judge the **question**... You happened to spot an **answer** that was incorrect/(*correct and you wanted to upvote it*) **while reviewing a question** that intention is completely unrelated to what you were doing in the first place, right? You are supposed to tell if the question is low quality or not - current answers have nothing to do with the review task and they should in theory be dealt with separately.